# Polaroid flash gallery interaction with html content (stack order)

Tags: jquery, flash, gallery, swfobject

I'm using [Polaroid Gallery](http://www.no3dfx.com/polaroid/) in a website intro, along with an html block, as shown in this test page: http://www.intellectualloyd.com/ladybug/

If you double click on a bag, the flash animation occurs and the image is shown bigger in the middle of the page. In this situation, the image (flash object) should stay in front of the html block (logo, etc..) and get back to the lowest stack order when you double click on it again.

In the code, there are two main divs:

- one which contains html block in the middle
- an empty one which will contains the flash object: `<div id="flashfullscreen" class="fOff"></div>`

After that, I load the .swf with SWFObject library, putting it in the #flashfullscreen div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var so = new SWFObject("polaroid.swf", "polaroid", "100%", "100%", "8");
// specify the url to the xml-file, default is photos.xml
so.addVariable("xmlURL","photos.xml");
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
so.write("flashfullscreen");
//]]>
</script>
```

In order to achieve the double-click effect, changing the stack order of the two divs, I've used jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flashfullscreen').dblclick(function() {
        $('#flashfullscreen').toggleClass('fOff');
    });
});
</script>
```

.fOff { z-index:99!important; } is the class style.
flashfullscreen div style has z-index:999.
block in the middle has z-index:100.

Roughly, I use jquery to remove fOff class from flashfullscreen div when double click, in order to set a higher z-index (999) for this block that will show up in front of the html block.

You'd probably see the problem.
If you double click on the large image to "close" it, it's ok and the stack order is properly reversed. But if you double click on the empty space around, the html block goes in front of the image, which is still "open".

I'm sure there's a simpler and complete solution to this, editing flash object or using SWFObject methods.. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player does not respect Z-Index.  No matter what index you specify, it will always remain on top *if* the SWF has `position: absolute` in CSS and a wmode of `transparent` or `opaque`. (FWIW, you should always choose opaque over transparent unless you truly need transparency due to the increased bugs and CPU of wmode transparent.)

Tutorial and examples here:
http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/placing-html-elements-over-a-flash-movie/

Comment: thank you, it's a better practice to place the html block over the flash movie but it doesn't solve my problem. I guess there's nothing left to do except try to add the block directly in the flash movie, right?

Comment: you can't have the HTML element be visible while underneath the polaroid photo unless you set the movie to be transparent. considering the CPU issues that could cause, it would probably be best to handle the whole page in Flash -- with a decent HTML fallback, of course! (What you're doing is possible with CSS3 and JavaScript in modern browsers, so I'd definitely recommend exploring that option)

Comment: y I understand.. I think we'll try to do the whole thing in Flash. thank you for your help